# Treating two classes as one in ImageDataGenerator flow from directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm currently working with the data generator provided with TensorFlow and I wanted to do some tests by turning my multi-class classification problem into a binary one.

My current folder layout is as such:

```
data/
├── 0/  <-- folder containing images of class 0
├── 1/
└── 2/
```

I'm currently loading it as follows:

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.5)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(input_size, input_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')
```

I also have a validation subset of course. Though, I'm struggling to figure out how I can make it so I treat class 1 and 2 as a single class without manipulating the actual data or folder structure.

I found a way to select which classes to use specifically, but that's there was in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following can help you:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.5)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(input_size, input_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

def transform_classes(args):
    """
    data/0/ -> 0
    data/1/ -> 1
    data/2/ -> 1
    """
    new_classes = np.array([0,1,1])
    x,y = args
    y = np.argmax(y, axis=1) # One hot to integer
    y = new_classes[y] # Changing the target
    y = np.eye(2)[y] # Going back to one hot 
    return x,y

train_generator = map(transform_classes, train_generator)
```

The idea behind this answer is that `train_datagen.flow_from_directory` will return a python generator, that we can transform using `map`.